# how to specify an order condition in Rails 3.2.13 with a polymorphic relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I feel like I have tried every variation of setting the order phrase in the following but nothing seems to work. I have

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :location_id
  belongs_to :location
  has_many :assets, :as => :assetable, :dependent => :destroy,  -> { order by position }
```

I have tried as a Proc, lambda, and I feel everyting else. Any ideas on how to make this work?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
has_many :assets, as: :assetable, dependent: :destroy,  order: :position
```